# I want to change the default color for the Fill and Border Color in the DrawerJs library

Tags: javascript, html, shared-libraries

Is anyone here familiar with the DrawerJs library?

here is the link:
https://github.com/carstenschaefer/DrawerJs/wiki

I am using this library in my web application, and my problem is that I want to change the default color for the fill and border-color of shapes. I have already managed to change the default color in the color-picker, but I still need to click the color in the color-picker for it to change its color.

I am using the drawerJs.standalone.js

I already tried modifying some default colors in the drawerJs.standalone.js and managed to change the default color for the color-picker, but I cannot find the click event that triggers the color change for the default.

like these one.

```
  ShapeBorder.prototype.updateColorFromObject = function (object) {
    var color = null;
    color = object.get('stroke');
    if (color) {
      this.currentColor = color;
    } else {
      this.currentColor = pluginsNamespace.ColorpickerControl.TRANSPARENT;
      //changed this part to black;
    }
  };
```

also this one.

```
// setup colorpicker for border color
    this.colorpicker = new pluginsNamespace.ColorpickerControl(this.drawer, this.options);

    this.currentColor = this.options.color;
    //// change this one also to black
    this.currentBorder = this.options.borderTypes[this.options.defaultBorder];
```

but still I need to click the color-picker to change the color.